# Is having a UIPickerView in a UIActionSheet acceptable?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

Is it acceptable (aka would Apple consider it acceptable) to have a UIPickerView in a UIActionSheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is acceptable.

set the frame of the UIPickerView

add the UIPickerView to the actionView

As I remember, actionView will be full screen in this case

```
UIActionSheet *actionView = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWith...];
UIPickerView *pickerView = [UIPickerView alloc] init...];
pickerView.frame = CGRect(....);
[actionView addSubview:pickerView];
[pickerView release];
[actionView showInView:theView]; 
[actionView release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is totally acceptable. To some degree its even encouraged.

Example code: [HERE](https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C11-Tables/22-View%20Picker) by Erica Sadun in her book iPhone Developer's cookbook. Chapter 11 Recipe 21

Comment: Nope, but the way she set up her code is pretty open abstract. Learn what controls what and you should be ready to roll

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
NSString *title = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"; // <--- Taken from Erica Sadun´s CookBook
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,485)];
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
[picker setDataSource:self];
[picker setDelegate:self];
[picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
[actionSheet addSubview:picker];
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:[[self tabBarController] tabBar]];
```

Please remember that you have to set UIPickerView´s dataSource and delegate .